# Type of adjunct

Tags: adjuncts

What type of adjunct is the prepositional phrase 'at all costs' (as in the below sentence)?

> Orders were given that the fugitive should **at all costs** be slain.

I am inclined to regard this adjunct as being a conditional one, since it appears to connote a sense of urgency: if the fugitive is not slain, then there will be dire consequences. At the same time, it would not to my mind seem implausible to gloss 'at all costs ' as being a manner adjunct, with the slaying of the fugitive (understood as a future event) being carried out desperately, the slayer doing all that is needed to perpetrate the act (even if that puts them in peril).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is an exhaustive conditional adjunct.

The meaning is similar to *whatever the cost may be*.

It does not actually say anything about the manner in which the fugitive is slain - slowly or quickly, painfully or painlessly, etc. - only making clear that the slaying must take place no matter the price paid to make it happen.

If we use the adjunct as a response to a question, it seems the only way to interpret it is as a conditional adjunct.

> Should the fugitive be slain?
>
> Yes, at all costs.

> In what manner should the fugitive be slain?
>
> ?At all costs.